# Why I am unable to mount a CIFS from my server?

Tags: centos, samba

I have setup the samba on CENTOS 8 like that:

```
[global]
    workgroup = WORKGROUP
    security = user
    passdb backend = tdbsam

[e-table]
    path=/mnt/md0
    browseable=yes
    read only = no
    force create mode = 0660
    force directory mode = 2770
    valid users = lena
```

and /mnt has the following permissions:

```
$ ls -l /mnt
drwxrwxrwx. 27 lena lena 4096 Oct 18  2019 md0
```

But I get the following error on /var/log/samba:

```
[2020/06/16 17:46:15.738033,  0] ../../source3/smbd/service.c:784(make_connection_snum)
  make_connection_snum: canonicalize_connect_path failed for service e-table, path /mnt/md0
```

At the same time the client retrieves the following error:

[image: error shown in client]

So do you have any idea why that happens? Does affect that on the same time an huge rsync operation is performed on this file as well?

Comment: Check the audit log for SELinux denials related to samba.

Comment: How I can a look for it?

Comment: The file is `/var/log/audit/audit.log`. The [official docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/using_selinux/troubleshooting-problems-related-to-selinux_using-selinux) explain how to look for problems.

Answer (score 0):

Based upon @Michael Hampton 's comments I enabled the following SELinux settings:

```
sudo setsebool -P samba_domain_controller on
sudo setsebool -P samba_export_all_ro on
sudo setsebool -P samba_export_all_rw on
```

And I could mount the folder on CIFS